# Woocommerce Show attribute in backend with custom value

Tags: attributes, woocommerce

Wordpress - Woocommerce.

I need for old and new product to show in the 'attribute' page all the attributes by default, maybe with a custom value if is possibile. So i don't need to insert one by one for each products but i can just edit the default.

Example:

All my products have Weight and lenght. I don't have the time to add a product select the attribute etc. etc. i want to show in the attribute section

Weight: EDIT
lenght: EDIT
(...)
Color: EDIT

IS that possibile :( ?

thanks

*Sorry for my bad english